# Going over a matrix while multi-threading

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, pointers

I need to create a program that gets a dynamic matrix and changes it to one dimension, for example 4x4 matrix will give 16 arrays length, where each index has a odd or even number, matching the index itself. The threads needs to go over the matrix at the same time and copy the odd and even numbers to the correct places in the array. The main thread needs to wait for the rest of them to finish before printing the array and every value with its respective thread. [It should come out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCj3p.png)

We managed to fix the segmentation fault that kept happening, but now we need to set it so that each thread runs right after the other but instead each thread runs 4 times and then it switches to a different one. How can I change it so it'll run as asked?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>



#define  CORE 4
int N;
int odd = 1;
int even = 0;
typedef struct my_thread {
    int** matrix;
    int* resArray;
    int threadId;
    int strart_raw;
    int strart_cal;
    int end_raw;
    int end_cal;
    int counter;
} my_thread;
void* createArray(struct my_thread* thread);
void main() {
    pthread_t th[CORE];
    int s_r = 0, s_c, e_r, e_c;



    int i, j, lines, columns, * intMatrix;

    printf("Type the N for the N*N matrix:\t");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int size = N * N;
    int result_Array[N * N];
    int retcode;
    int interval = size / CORE;
    int matrix_build_counter = 1;

    intMatrix = (int*)malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            intMatrix[i * N + j] = matrix_build_counter;
            matrix_build_counter++;
        }
    }


    printf("The matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            printf("%d ", intMatrix[i * N + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    struct my_thread thred_obj_array[CORE];
    for (int i = 0; i < CORE; i++) {

        thred_obj_array[i].matrix = &intMatrix;
        thred_obj_array[i].resArray = result_Array;
        thred_obj_array[i].threadId = i;
        thred_obj_array[i].strart_raw = (int)((i * N) / CORE);
        thred_obj_array[i].end_raw = (int)(((interval * (i + 1)) / N));
        thred_obj_array[i].strart_cal = ((interval * i)) % N;
        thred_obj_array[i].end_cal = ((interval) * (i + 1));
        thred_obj_array[i].counter = (int)floor((interval)*i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CORE; i++) {
        retcode = pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, createArray, &thred_obj_array[i]);

        if (retcode != 0) {
            printf("Create thread failed with error %d\n", retcode);
        }
    }
    printf("done");
    for (int i = 0; i < CORE; i++) {
        pthread_join(th[i], NULL);
    }
    printf("the result array is: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", result_Array[i]);
    }
}

void* createArray(struct my_thread* thread) {
    int j;

    for (int i = thread->strart_raw; i < N; i = i * sizeof(int) * N) {

        for (j = thread->strart_cal; j < N; j++) {

            printf("I am thread: %d  And my value is: %d ,  (%d,%d)\n", thread->threadId, (*thread->matrix + i * N)[j], i, j);
            if (((*thread->matrix + i * N)[j]) % 2 == 0) {

                thread->resArray[even] = (*thread->matrix + i * N)[j];
                even += 2;
                printf("-----%d ---even---\n", even);
            }
            else {
                thread->resArray[odd] = (*thread->matrix + i * N)[j];
                odd += 2;
                printf("---%d ---odd--\n", odd);

            }

            (thread->counter)++;
            if (thread->counter == thread->end_cal) {
                return;
            }

        }
        thread->strart_cal = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: compiling with: `gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o" ` results in a LONG list of warnings.    strongly suggest fixing all those warnings, then re-posting your code

Comment: regarding: `intMatrix = (int*)malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));`  in C, the returned type from the memory allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()` is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.  the allocation functions can fail.  so should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful (==NULL) then call `perror()` so the reason the system thinks the failure occurred is output to `stderr`